# ERD types confusion

Tags: uml, erd

I can't possibly understand the difference between these two diagrams :
http://wc1.smartdraw.com/resources/tutorials/images/erdexample.gif
and 
http://www.javaguicodexample.com/erdrelationalmodelnotes_files/erdrelationalmodelnotes014.png

they both are called **Entity relationship models**
I'm tryin to model my db using the first type!
Visio used to support it but not anymore 
any suggestions on a good software to model the db like the first pic

?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql workbench` to build the ERD. Mysql workbench can even export your ERD directly to sql statement to create the database. There is also another ERD creator / general flow chart tool `yEd Graph Editor`. Both of them are good ERD creators.